Unable to connect local Nexus instances to Azure Container Registry
I'm trying to set up three separate local Nexus instances (one for each data center) with Docker proxy configured to connect to our Azure Container Registry (ACR) for the project. The goal is to have each data center's Nexus repository act as a local cache for the images stored in the ACR, reducing the need to pull from the remote registry for each deployment.
I've followed these steps:
Set up Nexus instances for three different data centers using Docker Compose files (for two instances) and manual installation (for one instance).
Configured a Docker proxy repository in each Nexus instance to connect to our Azure Container Registry.
Replicated the same configuration across all three Nexus instances, including creating the same repositories.
However, after completing the setup, all three Nexus instances remain in a "Ready to Connect" state, and the repositories show as "Remote Available" instead of being connected to the ACR.
I've double-checked the credentials and configurations, but I can't seem to identify the issue. Has anyone encountered a similar problem when setting up Nexus instances to connect to an Azure Container Registry? Any suggestions on troubleshooting steps or potential solutions would be greatly appreciated.
Additional Details:

Azure Container Registry: Azure ACR
Nexus version: Nexus 3

Docker Compose file used:
version: '3' services: nexus: image: sonatype/nexus3 ports: - "8081:8081" volumes: - nexus-data:/nexus-data volumes: nexus-data: {}
Thank you in advance for your help!
current nexus setup
expected outcome
current nexus realms
current nexus repo config 1
current nexus repo config 2
current nexus repo config 3
